# How To Specify Excel HDR

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I use OLEDB to operate Excel 2010 file,the content likes this below:
1:the first row of sheet1 include Company No. and Company Name.
2:the second row is the real HDR such as EmployeeID,EmployeeName,EmployeeAddr and so on.

now I want use SQL statment select and update this file,there is a question,how to specify Excel HDR as second row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your file looks like this:

```
Row   Column A
1     Company information
2     Some other information
3     Status
4     A
5     B
6     C
7     D
8     E
9     F
```

You don't want to do anything with row 1 and 2. Row 3 contains real headers. Row 4 to 9 contains real data. First, let's create a named range. Assuming you are using Excel 2010, select A3:A9, go to Formula -- Named Manager -- New -- give name `usefulinformation`. Then use the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace StackoverflowExcel
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {

            using(var myConnection = new OleDbConnection(GetExcelConnectionStringByWrite()))
            using (var myCommand = new OleDbCommand())
            {
                myConnection.Open();

                myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
                myCommand.CommandText =
                    "UPDATE [usefulinformation] SET Status ='Imported' WHERE Status IN ( SELECT TOP 5 Status FROM [usefulinformation] )";
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                myConnection.Close();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static string GetExcelConnectionStringByWrite()
        {
            return
                @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\users\cys\desktop\Test.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=0;MAXSCANROWS=10;READONLY=FALSE'";
        }

    }
}
```

Notice the update statement. Instead of using `[Sheet$1]` I am using the named range `[usefulinformation]`. The only risk is that if more rows are added and `usefulinformation` named range is not kept up-to-date you may not get the right results. To overcome that, use a long named range even if many cells in that named range may not be used today.

After:

```
Row   Column A
1     Company information
2     Some other information
3     Status
4     Imported
5     Imported
6     Imported
7     Imported
8     Imported
9     F
```

Comment: Hi zfus,I'm very appreciate for your advice,I have followed your advice selecting A2:A1000 as UsefulInfo and run the code above but it doesn't work. Are you sure the SQL statement "UPDATE [usefulinformation] SET Status ='Imported' WHERE Status IN ( SELECT TOP 5 Status FROM [usefulinformation] )" can work? The IDE throws an exception :The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'UsefulInfo'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'UsefulInfo' is not a local object, check your network connection.

Comment: Yes, I ran the code successfully. Does your excel sheet have a named range called usefulinformation? I can bundle my code as a zip file if you'd like

Comment: @Michael I have uploaded the a solution to https://github.com/zedfoxus/Presentations. Go ahead and download [StackOverflow18627032.zip](https://github.com/zedfoxus/Presentations/blob/master/StackOverflow18627032.zip) and click on Raw. Unzip, open the project and run the application. Test.xlsx is in the bin/debug and bin/release directory. Check if the project runs well for you.

Comment: Yes,I selected A2:A1000 range named "UsefulInfo",but when I run SQL statemet above("UsefulInfo"  instead of "usefulinformation") ,it doesn't work,It's better if you can zip your code ,I'm very appreciate for your help,I think maybe my OLEDB driver(32bit) can't run on Win7(64bit).My Email:babylon3389@gmail.com

Comment: Hi Michael, I have uploaded the zip file on github. My previous comment has a link to the zip file.

Comment: Thanks for the shared,I forgot to refresh page and didn't notice your message a few minutes ago :)apologize!